# Android RelativeLayout: Rightmost child takes all the extra space no matter what I do

Tags: android, button, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with three child views laid out horizontally. I want the leftmost one to take up any extra space and the other two to take up only the space needed to wrap their content. The documentation says this can be done, but I can't make it work. Here's what I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nodeLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/launch"
    android:text="@string/launch_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nodeLabel"
    android:gravity="left" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/kill"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/launch"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/kill_label"
    android:gravity="left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is the `TextView` takes up all the space, and the two `Buttons` are not rendered at all. If I change `android:layout_width` on the `TextView` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`, then all three `View`s show up, but the third one, the `Button`, takes the extra space, which is not what I want. I also tried setting `layout_width` on the `Button`s to `0dp`, and experimented with other settings values, all to no avail.

How can I make the two `Button`s no bigger than needed to wrap their content, and have the `TextView` take up the extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the propery android:layout_weight="x".

It works like this:
if there are 4 views in a row and every one has a weight of 1. Then every view occupies 1/4 of the space. If one has a weight of 2 then it occupies 2/5 and so on. If one has a weight of 0 or no weight, then it just occupies as much space as its content does. The system adds all the weights together and then sets every view the proportional width.

In your case you have to weigh them something like 1, 0, 0.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece. I had a vague recollection of something that worked like that, but I couldn't find any reference to it. That's because `layout_weight` is a `LinearLayout` attribute. I changed the layout container to `LinearLayout` and removed the `RelativeLayout` attribute definitions, and it works the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Great! We are here to help. Good luck!